# Visual States for Grid

Tags: wpf, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to define a style for the Grid where I want to change the border thickness of the Grid based on different states. Like on mouse/pointer over, I would like to make the thickness 1 and in normal state (when point is not over the Grid) I want it to be 0.5
Also, my Grid has a textbox so when that textbox is in focus (is being edited), the Grid border should be set to 1 (like pointer over state).

Here is my code:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox
        BorderThickness="0"
        Height="40"
        Text="Text" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use style trigger to  change thickness in mouse over. For text box get focus you can use event trigger.

Comment: this link will be helpful for you to achieve this . http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Actually there is no Style.Triggers in UWP. Also, how I want to change the Grid's border not the border of the textbox. Can I bind the target element somehow where I want to change the border thickness property?

Comment: I have explained according to WPF. I think this should be same in UWP.

Comment: It's not, but I suppose there has to be a work around (for Style.Triggers). Will see. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are on UWP you can make use of Xaml Interactivity library to trigger this. An example:

```
<Page>
    <Page.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="HideTextBoxAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="TxtBx"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                From="1"
                To="0"
                Duration="0:0:0.2" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource HideTextBoxAnimation}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtBx" Opacity="1"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Height="40"
            Text="Text" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This is not the exact storyboard where your were waiting for but I think you get. Just change the EventName of the EventTriggerBehavior and the storyboard to suit your needs.

At the top of the page you'll need these:

```
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It can definitely be done in UWP. They don't let you use Style Triggers (why, I have no idea), but instead you have to use `VisualState`s and `Storyboard`s. They're a lot messier and convoluted than WPF Triggers, IMHO, but they do work and that's how all the UWP default styles work.

If you haven't already, you should check out the [default UWP styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299122.aspx). `Button` is a [good place to start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx). You can see exactly how they change the `Button`'s visual properties in response to the different `VisualState`s. Unfortunately - and this is where Triggers would have come in handy - the relationship between the input events and the `VisualState`s is all done in code, so if the built-in `VisualState`s for the controls you're using aren't adequate for your needs, you will need to set them manually in the code-behind. However, you'll still be able to use different `Style`s for the same control, which appears to be your primary goal.

Blend is also very useful for stuff like this as you can test out all your `Storyboard`s fairly easily.

Hope this helps. Incidentally, I gave up on Windows Store / UWP about a year ago and went back to straight WPF and haven't looked back. With the Desktop App Converter finally on its way, I don't see any reason to use UWP unless you want to be on the XBox, but that's your call. :)